# Styling CSS for Pardot form

Tags: css

I have a pardot(Marketing automation tool) form and I want to style the  input fields such as first name, last name . company and email in such a way that they should align themselves vertically ie. they should all start from the same point . Right now they start right after the label .
the CSS for the pardot from input fields is as below :

```
#pardot-form input.text {
                border:none;
                height:20px;
                padding:9px 10px;
                font-size:16px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:5px;
            }
            #pardot-form .field-label {
                font-weight:normal;
                font-family:"proxima nova", arial, sans-serif;
                margin-bottom:5px;
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;

            }
```

I want to target one particular input text filed eg say company so that i can move it left or right to align it with the input text filed just above it . How do I do that ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Input fields have a default display property of "inline-block" which allows them to flow side by side with other inline or inline-block elements.

Try adding `display: block` to each input that you would like to arrange vertically.

Thanks to Louis Lazaris for the default display properties:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Set width to 100%...see example:

```css
form.form {
  max-width: 600px !important;
}

form.form select,
form.form input.text,
form.form textarea.standard,
form.form input.date {
  width: 100% !important;
}

form.form p label {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" class="form" id="pardot-form">
  <p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required required-custom">
    <label class="field-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="40" onchange="" />
  </p>
  <p class="form-field  last_name pd-text required required-custom">
    <label class="field-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="80" onchange="" />
  </p>
  <p class="form-field  email pd-text required required-custom">
    <label class="field-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" />
  </p>
  <p class="form-field  state pd-select required">
    <label class="field-label">State</label>
    <select class="select" onchange="">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="3431478">AB</option>
      <option value="3431480">AK</option>
      <option value="3431482">AL</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p class="form-field  opted_out pd-radio required">
    <label class="field-label">Tell me more:</label>
    <span class="value"><span class="" style=""><input type="radio" onchange="" /><label class="inline" >I would like to learn more about...</label></span>
    <span class="" style="">
      <input type="radio" onchange="" />
      <label class="inline">I am interested in...</label>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="SUBMIT" />
  </p>
</form>
```